# Verifying a database with TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit, git-gui

I have never really used the **Git GUI Here** from the context menu in my **File Explorer**. I always use **TortoiseGit**.

However, today I decided for curiosity to use the aforementioned utility. I noticed on the File menu it had **Verify Database**. It did come up with some results:

[image: Verify Results]

Comments about dangling commits and blobs.

My primary question is how do I do this database **verification** with **TortoiseGit**? And related to this, what is the importance of the results returned to me?

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, no such function in TortoiseGit. Want to fire an issue? Go https://tortoisegit.org/issues :)

Comment: About your second question: see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery

Comment: @YueLinHo Added here: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/3048

Comment: @YueLinHo This is interesting: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck

Comment: @YueLinHo I still feel this question warrents an answer - atleast from the point of view of the dangling commits and  if / how to resolve them.